# Combining Rows in SQL Based on Common Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, full-outer-join

I have a list of states with a count being attached to each one. I would like to combine the rows that share a similar state, so that there is only 1 row per state and the counts are either the number or null.

**Query**

```
select COALESCE(t1.State, t2.State, t3.State) AS 'State', t1.DMECount, t2.TransCount, t3.ProCount 
from #TestTable t1
FULL OUTER JOIN #TestTable2 t2 ON t1.State = t2.State
FULL OUTER JOIN #TestTable3 t3 ON t2.State = t3.State
ORDER BY 'State'
```

**Current Result**

```
State|DMECount|TransCount|ProCount
MA   |19      |NULL      |NULL
MA   |NULL    |NULL      |1
MD   |NULL    |NULL      |1
MD   |8       |NULL      |NULL
MI   |1450    |1         |259
MN   |21      |NULL      |NULL
MN   |NULL    |NULL      |2
```

**Desired Result**

```
State|DMECount|TransCount|ProCount
MA   |19      |NULL      |1
MD   |8       |NULL      |1
MI   |1450    |1         |259
MN   |21      |NULL      |2
```

From other solutions I've looked at, it seems like grouping by the state and taking the MAX of the others may do what I need, but I cannot group by a field that has COALESCE being used on it. The COALESCE is being used so that way if one of the tables has a state that the others don't, the state column uses that value instead of NULL.

Comment: GROUP BY the current query result.

Comment: Would you provide the definition of `#TestTable1`, `#TestTable2` and `#TestTable3`? It would be very helpful if you could provide the sample data that when after populating those tables we can get the same result as you did with your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to include the COALSCE statement in your GROUP BY clause:

```
select COALESCE(t1.State, t2.State, t3.State) AS 'State', max(t1.DMECount), max(t2.TransCount), Max(t3.ProCount)
from #TestTable t1
FULL OUTER JOIN #TestTable2 t2 ON t1.State = t2.State
FULL OUTER JOIN #TestTable3 t3 ON t2.State = t3.State
GROUP BY COALESCE(t1.State, t2.State, t3.State)
ORDER BY COALESCE(t1.State, t2.State, t3.State)
```

Comment: Didn't know you could group by a function like that, it solved my issue, thanks!